# Javafx.webView not opening local page in NodeJS server

Tags: java, node.js, javafx, webview, javafx-webengine

I have a minimal javafx webview and a nodeJs server code. But webview doesn't open its local page *(http://localhost:8000/)*, after loading the page, the status is CANCELLED. Full sequence of statuses: READY > SCHEDULED > RUNNING > CANCELLED.

If you run the page 'http://192.168.54.1:8000' (localhost > ipv4) then it throws the error 'Connection refused by server'.

Please tell me what could be the problem?

WebView code:

```
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;

public class Web {
    private JSBridge jsBridge;
    private WebEngine webEngine;
    private javafx.scene.web.WebView webView;
    private Worker<?> engineWorker;
    Web(){
        webView = new javafx.scene.web.WebView();
        webView.setPageFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        webEngine = webView.getEngine();

        engineWorker = webEngine.getLoadWorker();
        engineWorker.stateProperty().addListener(this::engineWorkerListener);
        webEngine.load("http://localhost:8000/");
    }

    private void engineWorkerListener(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState){
        System.out.println("WebView status: " + ov.getValue());
        if (newState == Worker.State.FAILED) System.out.println("WebView exception: " + webEngine.getLoadWorker().getException().toString());
        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) System.out.println("WebView loading SUCCEEDED!");
    }
}
```

NodeJS server code:

```
const http = require("http");
const host = 'localhost';
const port = 8000;

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("My first server!");
};

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://${host}:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Can you open the url in a standard browser?  Could be a firewall rule blocking a non-standard port, but I do not know the cause.

Comment: I am not sure why sometimes you reference localhost and other times 192.168.54.1.

Comment: @jewelsea Yes, I tried opening in Chrome, jxBrowser, JCEF - it works fine there. But such problems occur on WebView, I would like to set up the correct work on this particular browser, since I want to use javafx. I tried to replace 'localhost' with ipv4 (192.168.54.1), which means the same thing, because I read on the Internet that it helped someone in solving their problem in opening a local page, but my problem is precisely that the browser does not know how to work with socket.io (and possibly other frameworks due to serializing complex objects to JSON)

Comment: @jewelsea I already solved this problem by changing the line res.writeHead(200) > res.writeHead('200', {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
After that, the page opened, but unfortunately this does not solve my main problem, where the page does not start when 'socket.io' is connected (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74210940/javafx-webview-not-load-page-with -socket-io)
Please see the question and share your knowledge if you can.

Comment: I suggest you [self-answer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with the solution you provided in the comment.  I know you have another problem related to `socket.io` use, but that appears to be a different problem from specifying the correct return code and content type to the HTTP response.

Answer (score 1):

Changing this line of code solved the problem and the page opened successfully:

```
res.writeHead(200) -> res.writeHead('200', {'Content-Type': ''});
```